# Best way to create floating notification iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, modal-dialog, toast

I've got a tabbed iPad application with just about each tab running a UIWebView. I'm getting all sorts of callbacks, like when a user tries to leave the corporate site (which only displays the company site to users). In this case, I pop up a "toast" style window that tells them to click a button to open the page in Safari. I also pop it up with a spinner and no text to indicate that a page is loading. The approximate look that I'm going for is used in lots of applications, but you can see it best when changing the volume on the iPhone or iPad. It's just a translucent rounded square that fades in and out.

Right now I've got it implemented on one of my tabs, and I did it by creating the objects (a spinner, a label, and a UIImage with the square) and then programmatically hiding and showing them using `[UIView beginAnimations]` and changing the label's text. It works perfectly but I've got these nagging things hovering over my interface in Xcode, and it takes a lot of setup to accomplish if I wanted it to be in another tab, which I do. I can't help but think that there's a better way to accomplish this. I thought about making and adding a subview, but that would leave a white background to the toast. What I'm thinking is creating some sort of object that I can allocate in a tab's view controller whenever it's needed.

What are your guys ideas, or have you done this in the past? I see it in a lot of prominent applications, like Reeder, so I'm sure it's been done more eloquently than I have done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Gallagher has a great class called LoadingView here [Showing message over iPhone Keyboard](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html).  I use it.

Answer (score 2):

[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) is a popular library for this, as well.